# firebase script tags are not being imported in html file when using vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am using the installed version from `VueJs` with works fine I also imported `MaterializeCss`
this also works fine and I imported `firebase firestore`, all in the `index.html` file.
But when i try to use the `db` `variable` in a other `vue` file, it says that `db` is not defined.I do not understand why I get this error because `Materializecss` works fine.
Here is my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBl17wo7ihuMdACz_iZ3T9rRYZ4_yjSRtI",
        authDomain: "school-boeken.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "school-boeken",
        storageBucket: "school-boeken.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "164926430822",
        appId: "1:164926430822:web:a97b3f7bdcec364beb97a7",
        measurementId: "G-M7QE3Y21N2"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
      var db = firebase.firestore();
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add code to show how you have tried this.

Comment: Do you  have something like `import firebase from '@/plugins/firebase.js';` and `const db = firebase.firestore();` in the Vue file which you want to use it in?

Comment: Yes I did try that but it gave me a error saying Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/plugins/firebase.js'

Comment: That's because for that you need to create a `firebase.js` file in a directory called `plugins` in which add that firebaseConfig etc and export it. If you have a different file structure that's also fine of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect `firebase` in `main .js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'


export const db = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBl17wo7ihuMdACz_iZ3T9rRYZ4_yjSRtI",
        authDomain: "school-boeken.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "school-boeken",
        storageBucket: "school-boeken.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "164926430822",
        appId: "1:164926430822:web:a97b3f7bdcec364beb97a7",
        measurementId: "G-M7QE3Y21N2"
}).firestore()

export const firestore = firebase.firestore()


new Vue({    
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then in the components you can use

```js
import {db} from '@/main.js'
```

Comment: Why do this in `main.js`? Isn't it much better practice to just do this in it's own `firebase.js` file?

Comment: I agree. Maybe you are right. I agree. Maybe you are right. But this option has the right to life)